# Video capture in JavaFX

Tags: java, video, javafx, jira

This is actually a question about the Java FX feature request process, and how to understand the information on JIRA. I find the jungle of forums and roadmaps and discussions completely unnavigable.

Specifically, the feature I'm interested in is video (e.g., webcam) capture:

JavaFx has come a long way, and I've recently found its realtime video capabilities to be functioning well. However, without video capture it cannot be described as a real rich media development platform. The feature request at JIRA is 5 years old and there are many frustrated users commenting on this continued absence: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090438. If I understand this correctly, this page tells me that Java FX 9 is when this feature will be introduced.

My question is: how do I know for sure when to expect video capture implementation in Java FX (if at all)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that 'for sure' nobody can tell us when video support is integrated - not even the guys from oracle.
If you need video support *now* i would recommend openimaj from http://www.openimaj.org. They support the software for win, linux and arm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: how do I know for sure when to expect video capture implementation in Java FX (if at all)?

Simple answer - you don't. I wouldn't even expect it in 9 (they generally use that as a placeholder to mean some future release, rather than guaranteeing it'll be in JFX9.)

The JavaFX media capabilities are much better than they once were, but still lacking; there certainly doesn't appear to be a dedicated media team working on JFX as there once was. If you really need something like this, I'd suggest using an external library (VLCJ works well for me, and has much better format support for playback than JFX too.)